# Project to second display with Mac via Bluetooth

Tags: macos, windows-10, display, bluetooth, external-display

I'm using my Windows 10 computer to have my TV as a second monitor, and I do this by using the "Project to second screen" feature built into the OS. We want to do the same thing with my girlfriend's Macbook but can't find any info on how or even if this is possible. It seems that if you have an AppleTV it makes it a bit easier, but is there a way to use bluetooth to connect to a second display with a Mac the same way you can with a Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bluetooth?  No.

With wifi?  Yes.  On the Mac side, you'll want to look for an app like Air Display.  Officially, if you look at the Mac App Store, you will note that they say Air Display is not compatible with Windows.  However, if you go to their page at [Avatron.com/air-display](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/) you will see that this is not a problem.

I'm sure there are other programs out there that can do the same thing, but this is the first one that leapt to my mind.

Comment: Forgot to mark this as the best reply. It would seem that like you say it is not possible to do that on a mac, which is a bummer (for her at least). I don't think it'll be an issue with compatibility as we'll only be using the TV as a second monitor to _either_ the PC or the Mac. Thanks for the info!